# How to determine if document.write() will overwrite the page, i.e. if current script's been loaded asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

If `document.write()` is called after the page is loaded, the whole page will get overwritten. This may happen e.g. when the call to `document.write()` is placed inside a script that's being loaded asynchronously. Would it be possible to find out within that script if this is indeed the case, without resigning `document.write()` completely?

Comment: Why not ditch synchronous `document.write` alltogether?

Comment: @Bergi, we're writing software for easy integration on third-party pages, and our software is heavy on dependencies. Async load is hard to support because: 1) we don't know what libraries does the page owner have, and whether they are loaded before or after our plugin, e.g., we might have one version of jQuery and they might have another, so we have to resolve conflicts after our libs are loaded; 2) integration procedure must be as simple as having a short snippet of code on the page, and that snippet of code shouldn't change when we update our deps (that's why we can't just write them out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.readyState === "complete")
```

This will check if the DOM is finished loading...